# how to define end of string

Tags: php

I want to add `"/info"` in the end of urls.  If the `"/info"` already exists, I would like to leave as it is.

I'm currently using:

```
if(strpos($url, "/info") === false){
    $url .= "/info";
}
```

But the above code works only if the url doesn't contain `"/"` at the end.

For example: if the url is `http://www.domain.com` then it works perfectly and the output is `http://www.domain.com/info`.  If the url is `http://www.domain.com/` then it shows `http://www.domain.com//info`.

How to avoid this?

Comment: Technically speaking, double slashes still work in URLs.

Comment: @ChristianVarga: *Technically*, though, the two URLs identify totally different resources.  If you're serving directly from the filesystem, Apache doesn't much care...but if you're routing URLs through a script to determine how to serve them, `/info` and `//info` can mean two different things.  And Google would probably consider them distinct as well.

Comment: @cHao Good points, didn't think about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to take that into consideration.

```
if(substr($url, -5) != '/info') {
  if(substr($url, -1) == "/")
      $url.="info";
  else
      $url.="/info";
}
```

Note I modified the first `if` to only check for `'/info'` at the end of the url; as Gareth did ;)

Comment: Because it only checks whether `/info` appears *anywhere*.

Comment: True, but since he's asking about something simple, it's likely something else is amiss, too ;)

Answer (score 3):

Trim the domain, then check the last five characters (in case the "/info" string appears elsewhere in the URL).

```
$url = rtrim($url,'/');
if(substr($url,-5)!='/info') $url .= '/info';
```

Answer (score 1):

consider following url :
http://www.domain.com/info/test/

if you use `strpos` in that way , you will get wrong result.
instead you can use substr and rtrim :

```
$url = (substr($url,-5) != '/info') ? rtrim($url, "/") . '/info' : $url;
```